# Menu screen is not rendering after integrating parse push notifications

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am following [Parse push notifications](http://www.parse.com) to push
notifications in to my app, but after integrating, my app is not starting. I
tried the same steps in a helloworld project and it is working, but in my project
the user should enter his/her credentials then the app should shows the menu
screen.

I am trying to push notifications onto menu screen after entering the
credentials, but the menu screen is not rendering. Here is the code related to
the login button which displays menu screen:

```
public void loginButtonClickListener(final View view) {
  emailTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailLogin);
  passwordTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordLogin);
  emailText = emailTextBox.getText().toString().trim();

  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Lisnx", 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putString("useremail", emailText);
  editor.commit();

  passwordText = passwordTextBox.getText().toString();
  if (emailText == null || emailText.length() == 0) {
    CustomToast.showCustomToast(this, Constants.USER_EMAIL_FIELD_EMPTY_ERROR, Constants.TOAST_VISIBLE_SHORT, layoutInflater);
    emailTextBox.requestFocus();
    return;
  } else if (passwordText == null || passwordText.length() == 0) {
    CustomToast.showCustomToast(this, Constants.PASSWORD_FIELD_EMPTY_ERROR, Constants.TOAST_VISIBLE_SHORT, layoutInflater);
    passwordTextBox.requestFocus();
    return;
  }

  try {
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
  } catch (Exception e) {}

  pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, null, this.getResources().getString(R.string.authenticateUser), true);
  Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      authenticateUser(view);
    }
  });
  thread.start();
}
```

Here is the code for the menu screen. In this I am using code to push notifications:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.menu);
  layoutInflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
  overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left,
      android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
  startService(new Intent(this, LocationService.class));
  GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
  gridView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
  gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
  gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

  peopleNearByIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.peopleNearByNotification);
  peopleNearByIcon.setOnClickListener(this);
  friendRequestsIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.friendRequestNotification);
  friendRequestsIcon.setOnClickListener(this);

  nameText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userName);
  nameText.setOnClickListener(this);
  userImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.userImage);
  userImage.setOnClickListener(this);

  try {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        GetOtherData getOtherData = new GetOtherData();
        getOtherData.execute();

      }
    });
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  updateNotificationAndPeopleNearbyCounts();
  updateImageNameStrip();
  Parse.initialize(this, "OFMsL2oQ5vcLVDcPDzzXix7aGvBr9OthzQt9MIjM",
      "cJXRcf818NOrfxRIHGuMv1nl9sU9WXYXNQ6fhbTY");
  ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
  /*ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
    testObject.put("foo", "bar");
    testObject.saveInBackground();*/
  PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MenuActivity.class);
  ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

}
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at LogCat? How about stepping over these methods line by line and seeing if one blocks?

Comment: i didn't see any problem in logcat ,dats y posted code here.

Comment: The problem is trackAppOpened call